# Get key name of a javascript object in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, dictionary, object, lodash, javascript-objects

I have some **Entries**, those entries have a **Category** assigned to them, and each entry has a **numeric Value**;

```
{
   category: "cat1",
   value: -100
}
```

This is my entry ^. I run a Loadash *GroupBy* to group all the categories.

```
const groups = _.groupBy(dataSource, (entry) => entry.category);
```

This snippet here returns like this:

```
{
    "cat1": [
        {
            category: "cat1",
            value: -100
        },
        {
            category: "cat1",
            value: +10
        },  
    ],
    "cat2": [
        {
             category: "cat2",
             value: -100
        },
        {
             category: "cat2",
             value: +40
        },
        //and so on...
}
```

The keys are the **Category** names. The objects are the related entries.

I need to run a consecutive *Map* with an embedded *Reduce* to reduce the arrays to an integer through the sum of each entry's value.

```
const categoryValues = _.map(groups, (element) => {
    return {
        categoryName: ???????, 
        //*I DONT KNOW WHAT GOES HERE ^, 
        //I NEED THE NAME OF THE CATEGORY TO BE HERE*
        categoryValue: _.reduce(element,(acc, el) => el.value,0),
    };
});
```

Thats because my graph api needs his dataset array to be formed by objects like this one:

```
{
   "categoryName": "cat1", //*THIS IS MISSING*
   "categoryValue": 999
}
```

How can I access the key name of each array? I need to know how the category is named, so that the graph will display its name.

What needs to be written where I put my question marks?

Comment: Try using `JSON.stringify(data, null, "\t")` and paste the resulting object instead of providing a screenshot of DevTools

Comment: Check out [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). It will give you the names and respective values, which you can then map over.

Comment: `element[0].category` will give you the name of the category Also you might want to change `element` to `entry` for your code to work so the category name should become `entry[0].category`.

Comment: try `const categoryValues = _.map(groups, (element, name) => {
  return {
    categoryName: name, //I DONT KNOW WHAT GOES HERE, I NEED THE NAME OF THE CATEGORY TO BE HERE*
    categoryValue: _.reduce(element, (acc, el) => el.value, 0),
  };
});`

Comment: take second parameter also as a `name`. It contains the name of the property

Comment: `_.map(groups, (element, name)`

Comment: use it like `categoryName: name`

Comment: @cZephyyr It should work

Comment: @rayhatfield I checked that out before writing my question, but call that on my groups object will bring up a "entries() is not a function" error. Do I need to cast it as object?

Comment: It’s a static method on Object. Call it with `Object.entries(groups).map(([categoryName, categoryValues]) => { ... })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map) says:

> Creates an array of values by running each element in collection thru
> iteratee. The iteratee is invoked with three arguments: (value,
> index|key, collection).

As you can see, the second parameter passed to the iteratee is the original key in the collection. So, just add another parameter to the iteratee and use that:

```
const categoryValues = _.map(groups, (element, name) => {
    return {
        categoryName: name,
        categoryValue: _.reduce(element,(acc, el) => el.value,0),
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the name of the category from the second parameter of the callback function. This callback function is called by the `lodash` library and when it calls `map` function 3 arguments (value, key, collection). [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map)

```js
const categoryValues = _.map(groups, (element, name) => {
  return {
    categoryName: name, //I DONT KNOW WHAT GOES HERE, I NEED THE NAME OF THE CATEGORY TO BE HERE*
    categoryValue: _.reduce(element, (acc, el) => el.value, 0),
  };
});
```

Comment: This works. Can you please explain why this works though?

Comment: How does it recognize as the name of the element?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// this is the simple way.

var arr = {
  iamkeysA : [1,2,3],
  iamkeysB : [4,5,6]
}

var keys_ = Object.keys(arr); // now you get the list of keys name.

console.log( keys_[0] );
console.log( keys_[1] );
```